# Dividing two Big Integers with mod in Java

Tags: java, cryptography, biginteger, modulo

I am working on a cryptography assignment with BigIntegers in Java.
And I have these two numbers:

```
s1= r mod(N)  
s2= r * x mod(N)
```

I know the values of s1, s2, and N but I don't know the value of r and I need to retrieve x. Normal division of s1/s2 doesn't work here. I have a hint that I need to use modInverse but I don't know where to use it here exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided the inverse exists (i.e. r and N are relatively prime) this will work:

```
s2.multiply(s1.modInverse(N)).mod(N)
```

This is calculating s2 * s1<sup>-1</sup> in modular arithmetic. The result is x mod N. Which is the same as x if x < N.